# Unable to use expdp over database link

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to use Oracle's expdp to export a remote schema using a database link.  I think the database link works fine, since I can execute `select` queries through it. When I try to execute `expdp`, I get this error:

```
$ expdp myuser/mypassword parfile="C:\\expdp_parfile.txt"

Export: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Dec 7 09:35:36 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production 
ORA-31631: privileges are required 
ORA-39109: Unprivileged users may not operate upon other users' schemas
```

I saw some suggestions to make sure the relevant oracle users had the IMP_FULL_DATABASE and EXP_FULL_DATABASE, and also DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE and DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE, so I granted those to both the local user and the remote user whose identity is used for the database link.

Still I get the same error.  What can I do to resolve this error?